# textbox hiding alignment in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have three columns in rectangle. Column A , Column B and Column C. Based on requirement I did hide Column A and show using expression. Do not have any issue in PDF when column A is showing. PDF have alignment issue when Column A is hiding. In PDF table is not showing alignment correctly, means Column B and Column C is going to the very right of the sheet.

How to display table in centre even though when Column A satisfy hidden condition. Please can anyone suggest me. tried everything I can with this alignment nothing worked.

Thanks.

Comment: any suggestions please

Comment: You could wrap a container around the table and align that in the middle of the page.

Comment: where do I need to add a container?

Comment: Around the table. So add a container and drag the table inside of it.

Comment: tried. does not  make any difference. I added rectangle and dragged the textbox inside rectangle. do I need to add anything more?